# C selective #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if **C** permits setting a selective `#define`.
Here is what I mean by selective:
If I have a structure defined:

```c
typedef struct mystruct{  
int (*pointer_function)(struct mystruct* ,struct mystruct);
...
} mystruct;

// and I have:
int main () {
mystruct s1, s2;
// when I do:
s1 = s2;
// I want my #define to recognize that on the left side
// I have mystruct type and use s1.pointer_function(&s1,s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The #define performs simple string substitution. It isn't context-dependent. You can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure which symbol you'd be defining, `s1` or `s2`. Not that is really matters, in either case you'd replace one of the names that you need so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C11, with the `_Generic` syntax.

```
#define MY_MACRO(x, y) _Generic((x), \
    mystruct: (x).pointer_function(&(x), (y)), \
    )
```

You can't do this in C99 or C89.  I don't know of any compilers with decent C11 support yet, so this code won't compile for a year or two yet.  From the GCC docs ([source](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)):

> GCC has limited incomplete support for parts of this standard, enabled with -std=c11 or -std=iso9899:2011.